# class org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I'm trying to parse below `json` file

```
[
  {
    "Department": "3",
    "Address": {
      "FirstLine": "3",
      "Second Line": "3",
      "City": "3",
      "State": "3",
      "Post": "3",
      "Pincode": "3",
      "Country": "3"
    },
    "Education": "3",
    "FirstName": "3",
    "DOB": "3",
    "OfficialMail": "3",
    "PhoneNumber": "3",
    "LastName": "3",
    "PersonalMail": "3",
    "EmployeeId": "3",
    "Age": "3",
    "DOJ": "3"
  },
  {
    "Department": "5",
    "Address": {
      "FirstLine": "5",
      "Second Line": "5",
      "City": "5",
      "State": "5",
      "Post": "5",
      "Pincode": "5",
      "Country": "5"
    },
    "Education": "5",
    "FirstName": "5",
    "DOB": "5",
    "OfficialMail": "5",
    "PhoneNumber": "5",
    "LastName": "5",
    "PersonalMail": "5",
    "EmployeeId": "5",
    "Age": "5",
    "DOJ": "5"
  }
]
```

This is what i have tried

```
try {
        obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("jsonExampl.json"));
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
        empid = (String) jo.get("EmployeeId");
        firstname = (String) jo.get("FirstName");
        lastname = (String) jo.get("LastName");
        DOB = (String) jo.get("DOB");
        String ae = (String) jo.get("Age");
        System.out.println("Employee Id:- "+ empid);
        System.out.println("First Name:- "+ firstname);
        System.out.println("Last Name:- "+ lastname);
        System.out.println("DOB:- "+ DOB);
        System.out.println("Age:- "+ ae);
        Map address = ((Map)jo.get("Address"));
        Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1 = address.entrySet().iterator(); 
        while (itr1.hasNext()) { 
            Map.Entry pair = itr1.next(); 
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue()); 
        }
        phnumber=(String) jo.get("PhoneNumber");
        personalemail = (String) jo.get("PersonalMail");
        officialemail = (String) jo.get("OfficialMail");
        department = (String) jo.get("Department");
        DOJ = (String) jo.get("DOJ");
        Education = (String) jo.get("Education");
        System.out.println("Employee Phone:- "+ phnumber);
        System.out.println("Personal:- "+ personalemail);
        System.out.println("Official:- "+ officialemail);
        System.out.println("DOJ:- "+ DOJ);
        System.out.println("Education:- "+ Education);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

The code is not working when I try to parse the `json` array, so I get:

`class org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONObject (org.json.simple.JSONArray and org.json.simple.JSONObject are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Please help
Thank you in Advance

Comment: you are trying to parse it to a JSONObject, while you should be parsing it to a JSONArray, the error message is pretty clear

Comment: Your top-level element is an array. array != object. array = list of things. object = thing with properties

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse it to JSONArray as in the comment above. This is the fixed code:

```
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(json);
        for(Object obj : array.stream().toArray()) {
            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
            String empid = (String) jo.get("EmployeeId");
            String firstname = (String) jo.get("FirstName");
            String lastname = (String) jo.get("LastName");
            String DOB = (String) jo.get("DOB");
            String ae = (String) jo.get("Age");
            System.out.println("Employee Id:- " + empid);
            System.out.println("First Name:- " + firstname);
            System.out.println("Last Name:- " + lastname);
            System.out.println("DOB:- " + DOB);
            System.out.println("Age:- " + ae);
```